# youtube-dl doesn't work with .bat files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, youtube-dl

I wanna handle my youtube downloading with a .bat file, like so:

```
youtube-dl -o path\%(title)s.%(ext)s --audio-format best -x ^
url
```

and it works just fine in the cmd, but when I put it in a .bat and run it, I get the following:

```
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: Cannot download a video and extract audio into the same file! Use "path\(ext)s.%(ext)s" instead of "path\(ext)s" as the output template
```

I can get it to work by replacing `%(title)s.%(ext)s` by `%(title)s%(ext)s.%(ext)s`. When I run the .bat, the cmd interprets it like so:

```
youtube-dl -o path\(ext)s.(ext)s --audio-format best -x url
```

and I get a file with name `(ext)s.m4a`.

How do I get a properly named file with the path I want?

Comment: try: `echo youtube-dl -o path\%(title)s.%(ext)s --audio-format best -x ^` and see what comes up.  You may need to replace a % with two %s.

Comment: `echo` made it just print the code, but simply replacing both % by %% worked. I'll accept it if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command shell may interpret the percent sign, followed by some other things, as a variable name.  If you want the program to receive an actual percent sign, you may need to escape it by using multiple percent signs.  So, try using two percent signs in a row.

If you use the `echo` command, you can easily see what is actually sent to the program (so you can see what the program actually receives), which may be helpful.

Comment: I verified, this is indeed the root cause of the issue.